# Use bash script in Fail2Ban Configuration

Tags: bash, sendmail, fail2ban

I would like to call a bash script in the mailing of Fail2Ban. The bash script calls a rest api to get the username of the blocked ip-address by fail2ban.

```
# Fail2Ban configuration file
#
# Author: *
#
#

[INCLUDES]

before = sendmail-common.conf

[Definition]

# Option:  actionban
# Notes.:  command executed when banning an IP. Take care that the
#          command is executed with Fail2Ban user rights.
# Tags:    See jail.conf(5) man page
# Values:  CMD
#
actionban = printf %%b "Subject: [Fail2Ban] <name>: banned <ip> from `uname -n`
            Date: `LC_ALL=C date +"%%a, %%d %%h %%Y %%T %%z"`
            From: <sendername> <<sender>>
            To: <dest>\n
            The following IP <ip> has just been banned by Fail2Ban after <failures> attempts against the acceptance environment of <name> on server.\n
            One or the following users could be the victim: \n 
            `/etc/fail2ban/restapi/getHttpSessions.sh | grep <ip>` \n | /usr/sbin/sendmail -f <sender> <dest>

[Init]
```

But however I got errors in the fail2ban log that no e-mail is sended

```
`/bin/sh /etc/fail2ban/scripts/getHttpSessions.sh | grep` 10.100.00.00 \n |/usr/sbin/sendmail -f fail2ban test@test.com -- returned 1
```

Is there some way to use a bash script in a fail2ban configuration file that lookups the IP-address in the bash created overview?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I got it working. Probably some issues within the syntax. Working code:

```
# Fail2Ban configuration file
#
# Author: Danny van den Berg
#
#

[INCLUDES]

before = sendmail-common.conf

[Definition]

# Option:  actionban
# Notes.:  command executed when banning an IP. Take care that the
#          command is executed with Fail2Ban user rights.
# Tags:    See jail.conf(5) man page
# Values:  CMD
#
actionban = printf %%b "Subject: [Fail2Ban] <name>: banned <ip> from `uname -n`
            Date: `LC_ALL=C date +"%%a, %%d %%h %%Y %%T %%z"`
            From: <sendername> <<sender>>
            To: <dest>\n
            The following IP <ip> has just been banned by Fail2Ban after <failures> attempts against the production environment of <name> on server.\n
            More information about the user:\n 
            [IP            | KEY] \n
            `/usr/bin/gethttpsessions | grep <ip> `\n\n" | /usr/sbin/sendmail -f <sender> <dest>

[Init]

# Default name of the chain
#
name = default
```